# Firemonkey how to set font color for selected text in TEdit

Tags: firemonkey

I'm trying to find a way to use styles to set the color of the selected text in a TEdit in Firemonkey.
In Delphi VCL, the text color by default changes to white (or perhaps a windows constant) when the text is selected, so that it shows clearly through the selection highlight.
In FMX, the default style is for the text color not to change. That results in the text being hard to read.  I'd like to set it so that it works like VCL, but I can't find anywhere in the style to set the text color of the selected text.
Thanks for any help you can provide.
Scott

Comment: You can only change the selection color, not the text

Comment: Thanks.  Then how would you accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: As that's not possible with Style, I would not do it :/ change selection color isn't enough ?

Comment: Thanks. It really looks much better if the text can go to white when the selection goes dark.  Some of the fields are color coded in the unselected state, so it's much more readable if the selection color can be distinctly darker, which then means the text should be much lighter to maintain readability. - And, as I said, this is the default functioning in VCL, so I must not be the only one who thinks this is useful.

Comment: Try changing the `ControlType` on your `TEdit` from `Styled` to `Platform`. It will ignore your style though.

Comment: Alex, Thanks.  That appears to make no difference.  I'm starting to think this is a bug, since the standard for Mac applications is the same as for Windows, in that when selected, the color of the text turns to white, but not in apps created using FMX